# Comprobar si un char es mayuscula o minuscula

Tags: c++

haciendo un ejercicio para identificar si un char es mayuscula o minuscula siempre me da el resultado "la letra es una vocal MINUSCULA" incluso si pongo otro digito ejemplo "a" "A" "f" "F", Siempre me da el resultado del primer if

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   
   char letra;
   
   cout<<"digite letra vocal: ";cin>>letra;


   if(letra == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u'){
       cout<<"la letra es una vocal minuscula";
   }
   else if(letra == 'A'||'E'||'I'||'O'||'U')
   {
       cout<<"es una vocal MAYUSCULA";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esa comparación está mal. Debe ser `if letra == 'a' || letra == 'b' ...`

Answer (score 7):

El condicional que has programado:

```
if(letra == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')
```

Hace las siguiente comprobaciones:

- `letra == 'a'`
- `'e'`
- `'i'`
- `'o'`
- `'u'`

La primera condición se resuelve como esperas, se comprueba si la letra es igual al caracter `'a'`. El resto de condiciones ... bueno, son **siempre** verdaderas.

Esto se produce porque para C++ las evaluaciones booleanas siguen el siguiente patrón:

- `0` -> falso
- Cualquier otro valor -> verdadero

Así, el caracter `'e'`, que se corresponde con el código ASCII 101, devolverá un resultado booleano de verdadero.

El caso es que el condicional final será equivalente a:

```
if (letra == 'a' || true || true || true || true)
```

Por lo que el `if` será **siempre verdadero** independientemente del caracter que estemos evaluando.

Para arreglarlo, tendremos que hacer una comparación por cada opción a evaluar:

```
if (letra == 'a' || letra == 'e' || letra == 'i' || letra == 'o' || letra == 'u')
```

Claro que si simplemente te interesa evaluar si el caracter está en minúsculas o en mayúsculas, puedes apoyarte en la tabla ASCII para simplificar el condicional:

```
if (letra >= 'a' && letra <= 'z')
    // minusculas
else if (letra >= 'A' && letra <= 'Z')
    // mayusculas
else
    // otro caracter
```

También puedes agrupar los caracteres en un `string` y ver si el caracter a evaluar pertenece al grupo:

```
std::string const minusculas = "aeiou";
if (minusculas.find(letra) != std::string::npos)
    // minuscula
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una función parecida en la web pero esta escrito en C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char letra;
    printf("Ingrese una letra: ");
    scanf("%c",&letra);
    if(letra >= 'a' && letra <= 'z')
        printf("\n-> Es minuscula ");
    else if(letra >= 'A' && letra <= 'Z')
        printf("\n-> Es mayuscula ");
    else
        printf("\n-> No es una letra ");

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Espero y esto te ayude

Comment: Un enlace como respuesta se considera de baja calidad. Te invito aleer [answer]. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta o elimina la **no** respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios desconocía que un enlace como respuesta se considera de baja calidad lo tendré en cuenta